# Clearing resources

Tags: php, performance

Is it possible to clear all resources in PHP?

I know that you can get all defined functions with [get_defined_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php)
with unset you can easily clear these resources.

But that's not enough for me. I have a script that runs a long time (~1h 30m) to execute many functions.. but while the executions the script collected informations that don't matter anymore.. the script exports products and get around 0.2MB - 0.5MB for each product (3200 products)

That is more than 600mb of memory usage. I optimized the script as good as I can, but I don't get it smaller.

I is possible to get all included files with [get_included_files](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) or [get_declared_classes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php); is it possible to clear these infos? Remove the classes (except some required like autoloader classes) or other included files so that I can free more RAM?

Or do you know other ways to optimize the server usage while execution?

Maybe it's a stupid question, but I would be happy for each hint to improve the performance of the PHP script.

Info of the script environment: the script runs on an old Magento version 1.4 that has huge problems with the cache and performance; an update to a newer version is at the moment not possible.

Comment: Usually the garbage collector is good enough to free any unused references itself, especially since it can detect cyclic references since PHP5.3. Do you _really_ reach 600MB?

Comment: Are you storing any data like sql records in variables? You could try writing to disk and then unsetting them.

Comment: From the sounds of it, you want to do a clean wipe of all resources in the middle of your PHP script. My suggestion is: don't. That sounds like it could lead to terrible things (especially since the script will probably still be dealing with them). Rather, you should go into the code and make it close each resource as it is no longer needed.

Comment: You should as said, export data to tempory file and clear all the memory about what is in the file. At the end, open each file and merge them... Use different script if required.

Comment: i use an old magento version and its currently not possible and too much effort to update the version so that everything still works.. i dont want, and we dont have the time, to change the core functions from magento to make it faster.. so i hoped that someone had an idea about this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a script that consumed up to 2GB of memory, and leaked memory like crazy (it uses Doctrine 1.1).

After `unset()ing` as much as we could, we then added `gc_enable()` to the top of the script, and `gc_collect_cycles()` in strategic locations.

This did help with reclaiming some of the used memory, but did slow the script down by a small amount.

Answer (score 2):

You've a lot of fonctions for clear ressource/memory :

`unset()` for variable

`mssql_free_result` for SQL

`memory_get_usage()` for the amount of memory, in bytes, that's currently being allocated to your PHP script.

ETC...

If you mix everything, you can decrease memory/ressource.

Answer (score 1):

The problem do not rely in the variables but in the algorithm.

In think The script cumulates all the values into a big "product object" array that will be serialized in the exported file.

To be memory savvy, it would be better to serialize each product once built instead of cumulating all products to export into an array before serializing.